# Algorithm to match sets with overlapping members

Tags: algorithm, set, match

Looking for an efficient algorithm to match sets among a group of sets, ordered by the most overlapping members. 2 identical sets for example are the best match, while no overlapping members are the worst.

So, the algorithm takes input a list of sets and returns matching set pairs ordered by the sets with the most overlapping members.

Would be interested in ideas to do this efficiently. Brute force approach is to try all combinations and sort which obviously is not very performant when the number of sets is very large.

Edit: Use case - Assume a large number of sets already exist. When a new set arrives, the algorithm is run and the output includes matching sets (with at least one element overlap) sorted by the most matching to least (doesn't matter how many items are in the new/incoming set). Hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: An idea is to convert sets to lists and sort each one of them. This way at least the comparison operation can be made more efficient.

Comment: How big are the sets? How many sets do you have?

Comment: Are you looking for overlaps within pairs of sets, or for "global overlaps"? What is better, two sets with 100% members overlapping, or three sets with a 99% member overlap?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - great q! individual sets are not very large (~< 25 members). total number of sets also in thousands. But unfortunately new sets come in all the time and hence have to "re-run" the operation. That's the real problem for me. Oh, and sorry for not clarifying. I believe I am solving for "global overlaps". In other words, when a new set arrives, the algorithm is re-run and the output includes matching sets (with at least one element overlap) sorted by the most matching to least. Hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: What goes into the set - strings, numbers, or something else? If it's numbers, are they ints or floats? If they are ints, is there a limit on them?

Comment: Are there "infinitely many" possible elements in the sets, or do they consist of a relatively small number (say the numbers 1 to 100 = small sets, any string up to 100 characters long = large set). Put differently - in your "thousands" of sets x 25 elements, do you have "approximately 10,000" different elements, or more like a few hundred? The latter would allow for some very efficient hashing.

Comment: set contain ids. no, there are absolutely a finite number of ids to match - total number of ids, in thousands. so definitely small & finite. would love to hear more on efficient hashing techniques. thx!

Comment: dasblinkenlight @Floris any thoughts guys? Thanks! So far my best option is Eyal's approximation algo suggestion.

Comment: Further notes: safe to assume each set consists of int ids, each ranging from say (1, 10000). Also safe to assume max num of items in each set is under 30.

Comment: One more question - is "most matching" absolute or relative. Does "1 2 3" have a better match with "1 2" or with "1 2 3 4"?

Comment: @Floris very good question. Will have to run a test to figure out which is best. For now, the higher the matching elem count the better and if both approaches have same number of matches they can receive equal scores. So in your example (1 2 3) is a better match with (1 2 3 4) then (1 2) because 3 Elems match vs 2. But interested in simpler, more scalable approach in general. And (1 2 3 4) equally matches (1 2 3) and (2 3 4 5 6) because both have 3 elem matching even though the 2nd set has more non-matching Elems.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford an approximation algorithm with a chance of error, then you should probably consider [MinHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash).

This algorithm allows estimating the similarity between 2 sets in constant time. For any constructed set, a fixed size signature is computed, and then only the signatures are compared when estimating the similarities. The similarity measure being used is [Jaccard distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), which ranges from 0 (disjoint sets) to 1 (identical sets). It is defined as the intersection to union ratio of two given sets.

With this approach, any new set has to be compared against all existing ones (in linear time), and then the results can be merged into the top list (you can use a bounded search tree/heap for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of possible different values is not very large, you get a fairly efficient hashing if you simply set the nth bit in a "large integer" when the nth number is present in your set. You can then look for overlap between sets with a simple bitwise AND followed by a "count set bits" operation. On 64 bit architecture, that means that you can look for the similarity between two numbers (out of 1000 possible values) in about 16 cycles, regardless of the number of values in each cluster. As the cluster gets more sparse, this becomes a less efficient algorithm.

Still - I implemented some of the basic functions you might need in some code that I attach here - not documented but reasonably understandable, I think.  In this example I made the numbers small so I can check the result by hand - you might want to change some of the #defines to get larger ranges of values, and obviously you will want some dynamic lists etc to keep up with the growing catalog.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// biggest number you will come across: want this to be much bigger
#define MAXINT 25
// use the biggest type you have - not int
#define BITSPER (8*sizeof(int))
#define NWORDS (MAXINT/BITSPER + 1)
// max number in a cluster
#define CSIZE 5

typedef struct{
  unsigned int num[NWORDS]; // want to use longest type but not for demo
  int newmatch;
  int rank;
} hmap;

// convert number to binary sequence:
void hashIt(int* t, int n, hmap* h) {
  int ii;
  for(ii=0;ii<n;ii++) {
    int a, b;
    a = t[ii]%BITSPER;
    b = t[ii]/BITSPER;
    h->num[b]|=1<<a;
  }
}

// print binary number:
void printBinary(int n) {
  unsigned int jj;
   jj = 1<<31;
   while(jj!=0) {
     printf("%c",((n&jj)!=0)?'1':'0');
     jj>>=1;
   }
   printf(" ");
}

// print the array of binary numbers:
void printHash(hmap* h) {
  unsigned int ii, jj;
  for(ii=0; ii<NWORDS; ii++) {
   jj = 1<<31;
   printf("0x%08x: ", h->num[ii]);
   printBinary(h->num[ii]);
  }
  //printf("\n");
}

// find the maximum overlap for set m of n
int maxOverlap(hmap* h, int m, int n) {
  int ii, jj;
  int overlap, maxOverlap = -1;
  for(ii = 0; ii<n; ii++) {
    if(ii == m) continue; // don't compare with yourself
    else {
      overlap = 0;
      for(jj = 0; jj< NWORDS; jj++) {
        // just to see what's going on: take these print statements out
        printBinary(h->num[ii]);
        printBinary(h->num[m]);
        int bc = countBits(h->num[ii] & h->num[m]);
        printBinary(h->num[ii] & h->num[m]);
        printf("%d bits overlap\n", bc);
        overlap += bc;
      }
      if(overlap > maxOverlap) maxOverlap = overlap;
    }
  }
  return maxOverlap;
}


int countBits (unsigned int b) {
  int count;

  for (count = 0; b != 0; count++) {
    b &= b - 1; // this clears the LSB-most set bit
  }
  return count;
}

int main(void) {
 int cluster[20][CSIZE];
 int temp[CSIZE];
 int ii,jj;
 static hmap H[20]; // make them all 0 initially
 for(jj=0; jj<20; jj++){
  for(ii=0; ii<CSIZE; ii++) {
   temp[ii] = rand()%MAXINT;
  }
  hashIt(temp, CSIZE, &H[jj]);
 }
 for(ii=0;ii<20;ii++) {
  printHash(&H[ii]);
  printf("max overlap: %d\n", maxOverlap(H, ii, 20));
 }
}
```

See if this helps at all...

Comment: thanks @floris. interesting strategy and like the low memory requirements due to bit based hashing. will need to think more about this.. sweet. had thought about hashing but not this approach.

Comment: Whether this strategy can work will depend on the sparsity: at 10,000 possible values and just 25 chosen, you end up with 25x16 bits to store "raw lists", and roughly 20 64-bit (10,000/(8*64)) "patterns". But the "count matches" algorithm is pretty sweet...